# Static IP for Kubernetes Pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have an application that runs on Kubernetes. A part of the application tracks the different pods deployed by their IP addresses. These IP addresses are stored in a database which is also running on a pod. The application picks up the IP address from this database only. But when a pod restarts, and comes up with a new ip address, the old entry for the pod takes sometime to delete. During this time, the application pings on the old IP of the deleted pod and an error is thrown. To solve this issue, I need my pods to restart with the same IP address. Is this possible in Kubernetes?
I have seen Calico but that does not solve the issue. Using calico, I can either assign one single static IP to a pod or an IP pool. One single IP does not work because the pods are deployed using deployment/statefulset yamls having multiple replicas. And if an IP pool is assigned, then also the pods will restart with a new IP from the pool. It does not solve the issue of the pods having the same IP.

Comment: No, IP are assigned dynamically. You could maybe use pod dns names or headless service.

Comment: The problem you describe is not at all unique to Kubernetes.  Imagine a data center where a network cable gets pulled unexpectedly or there's a software crash on the node, so you know of an endpoint but there's no longer responsive software there and you got no warning.  Can you solve the problem at the application or load-balancer level, maybe take an address out of the pool temporarily if you detect that requests are failing?

Comment: About Using Service:
The communication here is between the pods internally. Service is for communicating with the outside world. Can it be used for internal communication as well?

Answer (score -1):

you can try using service name instead of IP address